# Testing recording permission issue

Tags: avaudiosession

The Apple documentation for AVAudioSession Class Reference displays the following about the "requestRecordPermission:" method:

> …… This method always returns immediately: if the user has previously
>   granted or denied recording permission, it executes the block when
>   called; otherwise, it displays an alert and executes the block only
>   after the user has responded to the alert.

That is clear,but my problem is this: How can I get back (for testing purposes) to the situation where the user has not yet granted or denied recording permission? I tried to completely remove the app from the device but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reset location and privacy.

Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Location & Privacy